# Position a form on a form in vb6

Tags: vb6

I need to open a second form and position it in a particular location on the first form opened.

Explain: I added a panel to the original form and as I was putting controls on it, I got a message that I could not add any more controls. So...

There is an existing panel that I need to cover up with a second form and have it remain covered even if the original form is dragged about the screen. The second form will cover it, but I need to know how to position it in reference to the first form.

The only references I can find are how to position it on the screen, not another form.

Comment: Goodness gracious… How many controls were you adding? There's a reason why these limits exist; they are not simply arbitrary. Attempting to work around them by creating multiple forms is just going to produce a very sluggish application. Not recommended. Also, you are going to run into lots of problems with Z ordering, communication across forms, etc. What do all of these controls do? There's probably a better way of doing it, but I can't speculate as to what that might be without more information.

Comment: I inherited this program. It's old and bulky and very convoluted. I agree with you totally but can't see a good way around the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's certainly no easy way to do that (a form can't host another form).  The limit you encountered was the max number of named controls you can have on a form (254, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240865(v=VS.60).aspx).

However, a control array only counts once to that limit.  So instead of adding a new control (for instance text boxes) for every input field, add them as new elements of a text box array.  The difference in code is that you'll reference the text boxes by index instead of unique name (you can use constants as index parameters to identify the different input fields, such as name, address, etc).